# Pytest running unittest failed with Attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I created below function and it's working fine but i am struggling with creating unittest for this function.

Here's my function:

```
 def put_config_file_on_device(device, config_backup=None):
    try:
        runn_config = config_backup
        runn_config_database = running_config_from_database(device)
        if runn_config:
            raw_config = runn_config
        else:
            raw_config = runn_config_database

        new_file, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
        os.write(new_file, raw_config.encode('utf-8'))
        ssh = SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        handler = get_handler(device)
        passwd = handler._get_admin_passwords()[1][0]
        ssh.connect(device, username='root', password=get_cred('root'),  
                    look_for_keys=False)
        vendor = str(handler)
        if 'Juniper' in vendor:
            remote_path = f'/var/tmp/{device}.cfg'
        if 'Cisco' in vendor:
            remote_path = f'harddisk:/{device}.cfg'
        scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
        file_path = f'{filename}'
        scp.put(file_path, remote_path, recursive=False)
        scp.close()
        os.remove(filename)
        return True, f"File store successfully on the device {remote_path}"
    except Exception as err:
        return False, f"Failed to store config on Exception: {err}"
```

I created below unittest but it's not working. I am getting error while tetsinh the UT.
i have mocked all the dependencies but not sure what's wrong with the code. I get Attribute error for <class 'paramiko.client.SSHClient.

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('mock_config_backup', ['someconfig\r\n'])
    @patch("test.scripts.script.get_cred")
    @patch("test.scripts.script.os")
    @patch("test.scripts.script.SSHClient.")
    @patch("test.scripts.script.SCPClient")
    @patch("test.scripts.script.tempfile.mkstemp")
    @patch("test.scripts.script.get_device_handler")
    def test_put_config_file_on_device(mock_handler, mock_temp, mock_os, mock_ssh, mock_scp, mock_cred, mock_config_backup):
        conf = 'someconfig\r\n'
        mock_temp.return_value = new_file, filename
        mock.os.write(new_file, conf.encode('utf-8'))
        remote_path = '/var/tmp/devA.cfg'
        file_path = f'{filename}'
        mock_cred.return_value = 'xyz'
        ret = MagicMock() 
        ret.connect('devA', username='root', password='xyz', look_for_keys=False)
        mock_ssh.return_value = ret
        mock_scp.put = (file_path, remote_path)
        scp.close()
        mock.os.remove(filename)
        status, out = test.scripts.script.put_config_file_on_device(device, mock_config_backup)
        assert status and out == 'File store successfully on the device /var/tmp/devA.cfg'
```

getting below error.

```
    =============================================================================================== FAILURES ===============================================================================================
____________________________________________________________________________ test_put_config_file_on_device[someconfig\r\n] ____________________________________________________________________________

args = (), keywargs = {'mock_config_backup': 'someconfig\r\n'}

    @wraps(func)
    def patched(*args, **keywargs):
        with self.decoration_helper(patched,
                                    args,
>                                   keywargs) as (newargs, newkeywargs):

/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py:1368: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py:1334: in decoration_helper
    arg = patching.__enter__()
/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py:1437: in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <mock.mock._patch object at 0x7f0e60450240>

    def get_original(self):
        target = self.getter()
        name = self.attribute
    
        original = DEFAULT
        local = False
    
        try:
            original = target.__dict__[name]
        except (AttributeError, KeyError):
            original = getattr(target, name, DEFAULT)
        else:
            local = True
    
        if name in _builtins and isinstance(target, ModuleType):
            self.create = True
    
        if not self.create and original is DEFAULT:
            raise AttributeError(
>               "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
            )
E           AttributeError: <class 'paramiko.client.SSHClient'> does not have the attribute ''

/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mock/mock.py:1411: AttributeError
===================================================================================== 1 failed, 6 passed in 5.67s
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewong, updated the question with complete traceback. thanks

Comment: I fixed the attribute error by removing extra "period" after "@patch("test.scripts.script.SSHClient.")"

Comment: side note, make your function less complex so it is easier to test. look how many things you have to patch in order to get this test to work, that should be an immediate red flag